# Retrieve value from a one-dimensional array Jave

Tags: java

I have created a program containing of multiple classes where one class asks how many times to run the program and then creates an array of multiple scanner input-values from another class each time the program is run. (The values are vehicle, name and years, and these are accessible with getVehicle, getName, getYears)

I can manage to print out the arrays depending on how many times the program is running using this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<array1.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array1[i]);
}
```

but I would also like to print out one specific array-element from each array. Lets say the arrays are:

```
[car, James, 2]
[bus, Anna, 3].
```

How can I access the numbers 2 and 3 (years)? I can't seem to know how to call the elements no matter how much I try. When I call theclass.getYears() in the loop I only get the last input but not the elements from both arrays.

Comment: `array[i][2]` gives the third element of the second arrays.  However it is not clear that you have two arrays, or what the structure of your class is if you don't.

Comment: Perhaps you could put your code into the question? As text, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but if your array consists of objects then what you could do is

```
for(int i=0;i<array1.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array1[i].getYears());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear about your issue. But I have an idea.

When you are creating your arrays, you can add the "Years" value to an `arrayYears` so you can access all your years data.

Then you might just print the `arrayYears` with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayYears.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayYears[i]);
}
```

You might add all the vehicle arrays to an array of all te vehicles!
Then you just use:

```
int n = numberOfVehicles;

for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
 
   System.out.println(allVehicles[i][2]);

}
```